# Querying an inexisting field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity **Paper** which is connected to the paper table in my project.
In this entity, I have a field **title**.

The problem is that the field title can have some **html tags** inside and I need to make some query on this field. The queryes are **without html tags**.

My idea was to create an extra variable in my entity: **title_without_html**:

```
protected title_without_html;

/**
 * Get title_without_html
 *
 * @return text
 */
public function getTitle_without_html()
{
    return  strip_tags($this->title);
}
```

And also in the constructor, I am creating the title_without_html.

Is this possible? If yes, how to do it properly. Actually, I am getting an error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 61 near 'title_without_html': Error: Class SciForum\Version2Bundle\Entity\Paper has no field or association named title_without_html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code miss a `$`, and you should avoid not camelCase methods (for consistency with the Doctrine2 generated ones).

Also, do not rely on the constructor: Doctrine2 do not call the constructor when fetching existing from the database.

This must work:

```
<?php

class Toto {

    public function getCleanTitle()
    {
        return strip_tags($this->getTitle());
    }
}
```

You don't have to set a property for this instead you are calling this getter a lot of times (then, a property could be used for caching the result of `strip_tags`).

Comment: thanks for the reply. The think is that I have to use the QueryBuilder in order to query my database. And there I am facing this problem.

Comment: I have missunderstand the question, your code example is not the right path.

What you need is tricky, there is no `strip_tags` in MySQL, you need to perform a search by words on the field, and that's slow.

The best advice I can gave is to actually add a real column on the table, with the clean and stripped title. Or search on a slug string if you have one.

Comment: Thank you Damien, that's what I have also thinked about. Or simply generate an xml file which will be updated daily with a cronjob. So, instead of searching in the database, I can search in the xml file, which is also fine. I know that there is no strip_tags in MySQL, but have though that something similar was proposed by Doctrine. Apparently not.